# Makefile - multiple targets, automatic dependecies

Tags: c++, makefile

I am working on a big project in C++.
It consists of several target executables, but most of them uses common classes.
My working directory is something like:

```
.
..
Classes/
    File.h
    File.cpp
    Encryption.h
    Encryption.cpp
    Database.h
    Database.cpp
Bin/ (I want my objects to be compiled there)

FirstProgram.cpp
SecondProgram.coo
ThirdProgram.cpp
Makefile
```

1. Some of my classes use external libraries. For example that to compile Encryption.cpp i need to add -lssl to target. Is there any way to make my makefile know it? Right now I must add -lssl everywhere where I use Encryption.o
2. I'm a little bit tired of looking which objects every of my target use and writing them in makefile. Is there any way to make compiler find all required .o and automaticaly compile them?
3. I want to store compiled files in Bin/ directory and avoid having them recompiled everytime I run make.

Right now my makefile looks like:

```
CXX=g++
FLAGS=-g -Wall -std=c++11
CLASSES=./Classes

Bin/%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(FLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

Bin/%.o: $(CLASSES)/%.cpp
    $(CXX) $(FLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

FirstProgram: Bin/File.o Bin/Encryption.o Bin/Database.o
    $(CXX) $(FLAGS) -o Bin/$@ $^ -lssl `mysql_config --cflags --libs`


SecondProgram: ... Bin/... Bin/...
    $(CXX) $(FLAGS) -o Bin/$@ $^ ??? additional libs there
```

Comment: With gcc you can generate dependency rules for headers, that can be included in your current makefile. Check the [`-M`, `-MM`, etc.](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options) options.

Answer (score 0):

For 1) You can use something like this:

```
CRYPT_TARGETS := FirstProgram ThirdProgram

$(CRYPT_TARGETS): LDLIBS += -lssl
$(CRYPT_TARGETS): Bin/Encryption.o

Bin/FirstProgram: Bin/File.o Bin/Database.o
    $(CXX) $(FLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDLIBS) `mysql_config --cflags --libs`

Bin/ThirdProgram: Bin/Astronomy.o Bin/KitchenSink.o
    $(CXX) $(FLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDLIBS) `mysql_config --cflags --libs`
```

(Note how I changed the target names; where a rule is intended to build a file, the target should be the exact name of the file.)

I don't think that 2) is a good idea. As you edit the code, you should be aware of which components you add and remove from a binary, so it isn't that much extra work. And there's no way Make can know that an object *that doesn't exist* is needed, unless you impose naming conventions on yourself that aren't part of the language (if you like that idea, let us know and we'll show you how). And then there are `main` conflicts... If the lists of objects are getting long, and overlap a lot, maybe you should build libraries.

3) is a good idea, and it looks as if your makefile can do it already.